# How do I generate a pdf in memory in ReportLab

Tags: python, reportlab

In my case I want to generate a PDF in memory in our Flask app so I can directly send it to the user as download instead of saving it to disk first.

Our code now:

```py
import os
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4


# normally this in a class but I simplified it for the example
c = canvas.Canvas(os.path.join("mypath", "report.pdf"), pagesize=A4)
c.drawString(100, 100, "Hello World")
c.save()
```

Answer (score 9):

To save it direcly in memory use `io.BytesIO`

```py
from io import BytesIO
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4


buffer = BytesIO()
c = canvas.Canvas(buffer, pagesize=A4)
c.drawString(100, 100, "Hello World")
c.save()

# then do something with buffer, for example:
pdf = buffer.getvalue()
```

Comment: Aha! I was looking for this! Thank you.

Comment: Good answer.
See also the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/outputting-pdf/